# How to search through children JSON with LINQ

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have the following JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Smith",
    "lastName": "Bill",
    "emails": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "Bill@Smith.Com",
        "dateCreated": "2017-05-11T10:18:52.3224545-07:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "Bill@gmail.com",
        "dateCreated": "2017-05-11T10:20:05.9283127-07:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "emails": []
  }
]
```

The email model object is inside the person.

I want to know how to use an LINQ statement to return me all the people that have emails that match some input. Such as if I search for "Bill@gmail.com", it would only return

```
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Smith",
        "lastName": "Bill",
        "emails": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "Bill@Smith.Com",
            "dateCreated": "2017-05-11T10:18:52.3224545-07:00"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "Bill@gmail.com",
            "dateCreated": "2017-05-11T10:20:05.9283127-07:00"
          }
        ]
      }  
    ]
```

It should look something like the follow?

```
var personWithEmail = People.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == i);
```

except this is only finding the People with some ID while I want to drill down to their children's email and search if the emails match.

Comment: What did you try with going down to the child properties? You're on the right track, and the answer isn't much further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `People` is a collection of `Person`

where

```
public class People : Collection<Person> {  }

public class Person {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public IList<Email> emails { get; set; }
}

public class Email {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Drill into the child properties.

```
var email = "Bill@gmail.com";
var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjecct<People>(json);
var peopleWithEmail = people.Where(p => p.emails.Any(e => e.email == email));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another example to the list:

```
string input = "Bill@gmail.com";
List<Peeps> tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Peeps>>(json);
//returns the base object
var test = tmp.Where(a => a.emails.Any(b => b.email == input));
//returns only the email object
var testDuece = tmp.Where(a => a.emails.Any(b => b.email == input)).Select(c => c.emails.Where(a => a.email == input));



public class Peeps
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public List<Emails> emails { get; set; }
}

public class Emails
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string dateCreated { get; set; }
}
```